# Nvim is apparently overwriting an already existing file

Tags: python, terminal, neovim

I'm running a script that listens to keyboard presses so that whenever I press the "t" key a new terminal window opens with a nvim process already running . I'm doing it via the following:

```
# open_vim is called when the t key is pressed
def open_vim(self, compile_latex):
    f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+', delete=False, suffix='.tex')

    f.write('$$')
    f.close()
    config['open_editor'](f.name)
    [more code ...]
```

where `open_editor` is a function defined in`config.py` like so

```
def open_editor(filename):
    subprocess.run([
        'gnome-terminal',
        '--geometry', '60x5',
        '--name', 'popup-bottom-center',
        '--', "nvim",
        f"{filename}",
    ])
```

So the expected behavior is that when the t key is pressed , `open_vim` is ran , a tempfile f is created with write permissions and "$$" is written in the file. Next , a new terminal window is opened where nvim opens the already existing file (mind you that f.name is something of the sort /tmp/tmpfilename.tex) . But instead nvim opens a file with the same name as f but treats it as new file, that is it's an empty file.

The oddest thing is that if I run the code block I mentioned in isolation , the part I selected from`open_vim` above, it runs as expected. But if the same code bock is called in the `open_vim` function call I've observed the following behavior by delaying the execution of `config.['open_editor'](f.name)` with `time.sleep()` : the tmp file is created, if I cd into `/tmp` and use cat on it i can see it has $$ as its contents. But as soon as `open_editor` is executed , the file vanishes from `/tmp` . So I'm inclined to think that somehow nvim is deleting the file and creating a new one on top of it, but i know that is very unlikely.

Another thing is if I change `open_editor` to:

```
def open_editor(filename):
    subprocess.run([
        'urxvt',
        '-geometry', '60x5',
        '-name', 'popup-bottom-center',
        '-e', "vim",
        f"{filename}",
    ])
```

that is, i change the tty to urxvt, it works as intended in `open_vim`.
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 with the zsh shell and NVIM version  `v0.10.0-dev`